# Load Directive Dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a function func() in my controller A which is invoked from some directive A, now on call of this function, i want to load/reload a directive B on the same page, what could be the possible options?

Comment: What do you accomplish?

Comment: Yep actually there are 2 directives one loads some data and displays it, another one on the basis of the data's count displays a progress bar, i want to share the data, i have constraints on using $emit etc. so i am doing it through making a callback to func in the main controller, now the directive B loads before the data is rendered on A and hence the progress bar isnt updated, so i want to reload that

Comment: Can you show your efforts? If possible include a plnkr (or similar) to showoff your problem.